# how to make a js function public in angular 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm using Angular 5 to develop my application.
In assets/js folder, I have a js file `test.js`. I have a variable `data` and a function `Loaddata()` in this js file. I want to be able to access these in my app.component.ts.

I was able to make the variable scope public and was able to access it in component.ts, but I failed to do the same with the function.

This is the process I followed for the variable:
1. Add reference of js file in `angular-cli.json`

```
        "scripts": [
                "assets/js/test.js"
         ]
```

2. Added the variable name in typings.d.ts file.

```
       declare var data:any;
```

Now I was able to access this variable in app.component.ts.
I want to be able to access even the function in the similar manner.
Can anyone explain me how to do it.

Comment: import 'test.js' your app.component.ts file and declare var myExtObject: any; and access your Loaddata using myExtObject.Loaddata()

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an awesome use case for using an Injectable Service. Create a loadData.service.ts file in the src/app directory of your application(if you are using Angular CLI), and then format it like this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoadDataService {
    data = [
        // Your Data Here
    ]
    constructor() {};

    loadData(params?) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need to use that function in a component, just import the service into your component, create a local instance of it in your constructor, and then use it!
To access the data, just set it equal to another variable in that components constructor.

```
import { LoadDataService } from '../loadData.service';

@Component({
    //whatever
})

export class YourComponent {
    dataFromService: [];
    constructor(private loadDataService: LoadDataService) {
        this.dataFromService = this.loadDataService.data;
    }

    runThisToGetData() {
        this.loadDataService.loadData(yourParams).subscribe(r => r);
    }
}
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

You could just use exports to do what you are asking for.

```
foo.js

module.exports = {
  hello: () => alert('hello from foo!')
};
```

EDIT ---- Fixed syntax

```
bar.js

const foo = require('./foo.js');
foo.hello();
```

Comment: This example shows how to access function from one js file to another. But I need to access the js function in app.component.ts

Comment: Hey take a look at this plunkr for an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/bBeoJlCo3wDqfHeYFby5?p=preview